# Spoiler-Box styling inconsistency of links

Tags: bug, design, spoilers

Compare:

### Correct styling in quote boxes

> Text [Link](http://scifi.example.com) Text

### Broken styling in spoiler boxes

> Text [Link](http://scifi.example.com) Text

When displayed the link styling appears not to use the site-specific theme.

In Opera 12, hovering over the box looks like the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The CSS looks like this was intentional - there's a lone rule for `.spoiler a { color: #222222; }`.  And yes, it looks bad on FF as well.